# Why is my timer counting down by 3 every second?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdate

I have a timer that's counting down by 3. I'm triggering the timer in the *viewDidLoad* method where I'm also querying time variables from Parse.

Here's my code where the timer function is:

```
    var createdAt = object.createdAt
            if createdAt != nil {

                let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
                let comps = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: createdAt as NSDate!)
                let hour = comps.hour  * 3600
                let minute = comps.minute * 60
                let seconds = comps.second


                self.timerInt.append(hour + minute + seconds)

                var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDown"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


            } 

            }

        }


    })
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

I've tried changing around the `self.tableView.reloadData()` because I'm assuming that it's a reloadData problem.

Here is my countdown function:

```
       func countDown() {
        //timerInt is an array where I'm storing the Int values.
        for i in 0 ..< timerInt.count {

            let hours = timerInt[i] / 3600
            let minsec = timerInt[i] % 3600
            let minutes = minsec / 60
            let seconds = minsec % 60
       print(String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds))
          timerInt[i]--

        }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I want this all to happen in the *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method..

Here is *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method:

```
  let hours = timerInt[indexPath.row] / 3600
    let minsec = timerInt[indexPath.row] % 3600
    let minutes = minsec / 60
    let seconds = minsec % 60

  //defining the time 

    myCell.secondLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)

             //formatting the time


    return myCell
```

Any ideas as to what is making it trigger 3x?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stupid of me. Realized that if I'm querying 3 objects from Parse the seconds count down by 3. If I'm querying 4, then the seconds count down by 4.

The problem was where I'm triggering the timer method:

`var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDown"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

I need to trigger it OUTSIDE of where I'm querying. Because if it's triggered there, then it's been triggered with the amount of objects I'm querying.

Now I put the `timer` variable like this and it works :) :

```
      var createdAt = object.createdAt
            if createdAt != nil {

                let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
                let comps = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: createdAt as NSDate!)
                let hour = comps.hour  * 3600
                let minute = comps.minute * 60
                let seconds = comps.second


                self.timerInt.append(hour + minute + seconds)


            }


            }

        }

         var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDown"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    })
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Note, the `}` are from other closures within my *viewDidLoad*.